# Outdated information in jwt token payload

Tags: json, web, token, jwt, payload

As written in [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/introduction/) "The payload contains any arbitrary information in the form of claims that we as developers find useful for our applications.". So i think it would be convenient to put there `username`, `email`, and so on. In this case i have no need to get this information from database or file system during authentication process. It is being touted as an advantage if app is distributed across many servers.

But I see here is one annoying obstacle. What if a payload was changed as a result of changing user account information? All old issued tokens stays valid since a signature is still valid. So i'll get wrong user account information from old token payload.

I missed something in idea behind jwt tokens?

Answer (score 0):

There's an optional claim `exp` for JWTs that specifies the expiry time after which tokens render invalid and should be rejected by the receiver. The idea behind JWT tokens is that you issue them with an `exp` timestamp that says until when the information in the JWT is valid.

If your user account information changes on a daily basis, the `exp` should be no longer than 24 hours ahead of the JWTs issuance time. After that timestamp the sender should go out and get a new JWT before sending it to the recipient so the information in the new JWT is fresh.

Comment: imho `exp` claim exists for security reason only. It prevents endless using of stolen access token. User is free to change his/her account information at any moment.

Comment: it may change at any moment but the question is do you really need to deal with it real time: if no then set the exp window to what you can deal with, if yes then don't include the information in the JWT but make a callout to retrieve it "just in time"

Comment: I not clearly understand what exp window do you mean?